# Replace the Word Before the search term

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to be able to use `replace(searchvalue, newvalue);` and a user input that would be the search term.

An example would be `replace(input,"example text");`

But what I want is to be able to have the search term, but instead of replacing the search term, replace the space in front of it.

Ex. is the sentence: `"Hi, I am using js to create this!"`

and user inputs `"js"` `replace(input, "html and ");`

but instead of replacing `"js"`, replace the space in front. So the output sentence would be:

`"Hi, I am using html and js to create this!"`

Would there be anyway to do this with replace?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: @MattBurland What is one that I could use? I only know a few but none that would do the thing I need.

Comment: Look up some tutorials on regular expressions, there are tons of them out there. You could start with something like `"Hi, I am using js to create this!".replace(/ (js)/, " html and $1")`

Comment: Or more generally, using the constructor to create dynamic regex: `"Hi, I am using js to create this!".replace(new RegExp(" (" + term + ")"), " html and $1")` where `term = "js"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function to handle the replacement in `string.replace`.

```
var newString = 'Hi, I am using js to create this!'.replace('js', function(match) {
   return 'html and ' + match;
});
console.log(newString); // ... using html and js ...
```

In the above example I prepend "html and " to the variable match (which has the value of "js").  There is a lot of flexibility when you use a regex instead of a string to find the match.

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**